# Wordpress columns, centered, but above each other on mobile

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

So I have a responsive theme and I want the home page to have a few columns that stay centered next to each other while on the computer... but when on the phone I would like them to go one above another... while each still being centered.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what have you been doing?

Comment: Well, I know what I was doing was completely wrong. I already deleted it.

But it was basic <div style"... with widths of 30% for each of the three divs.

First two were float left, last was float right. How do I get them to stack on a mobile phone?

Comment: Without code all we would be doing is guessing.

Comment: Well, just the inline style for a div to create three columns that stack over each other on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the link to your page or set up a codepen snippet may be?

Also, for using on mobile and making them show better, use a width like, say, 31% for each div, with 3% margin on right of each, and make all

```
float:left
```

so that it shows better on mobile, and then for lower resolution media queries like, say , 480px or lower, use

```
width:100%
```

for these divs. So that they show perfectly on mobile devices with appropriate widths.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well it's on a wordpress site, so I would be able to just put it directly in the content for the page, the site is phillysuburbanhomes.com

Comment: Are you talking about the input form? if so, do you want Max-Price etc...the columns with 50% width to be full width? kindly confirm.